# Quel est le nom du son de vibration des lèvres indiquant la perplexité ?

Tags: interjections, onomatopées, son, transcription

Je transcrit actuellement des enregistrements de discussions entre une chercheuse et ses participants. Il est important que toute hésitation, le son, et parfois même le ton de la phrase soit retranscrit pour les besoins de l'étude.

Dans l'un des enregistrements, la participante émet ce son que tout le monde connaît, mais dont a ma surprise je ne connais pas le nom : Cette vibration des lèvres en expulsant de l'air qui exprime la perplexité ou l’indifférence (et aussi le son d'un pet, admettons le)

Après quelques recherches j'ai trouvé les éléments suivants :

- Il pourrait s'agir d'une onomatopée, bien que je n'ai pas trouvé exactement laquelle (proche de *pfff*, *brrr* et de *prout*). De plus l’onomatopée est censée imiter un son, or ce n'est pas ici l'intention. Il s'agit plus d'un son qui aurait un sens propre.
- Il pourrait s'agir d'une interjection, vu qu'il s'agit d'un mot autonome qui transmet une émotion
- De même il pourrait s'agir d'un mot-phrase puisqu'il remplace a lui seul la phrase "Je ne sais pas" ou "Je m'en fiche"
- Le son serait représenté par le graphe ʙ̥ ou ʙ dans l'alphabet phonétique (Consonne roulée bilabiale voisée ou sourde, je n'ai pas compris la différence). La page wikipedia de ce son mentionne d'ailleurs son absence du Français à l'exception du grelottement de froid et du son que je cherche mais qui n'est pas nommé.

Voila ou j'en suis de mes recherches. Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'indiquer quel est l’appellation "officielle" de ce son et me suggérer un moyen de le retranscrire de façon a ce que tout lecteur comprenne de quoi je parle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne lui connais pas d'appellation "officielle" mais ce mot peut être transcrit par **prrt**.

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille éviter de le qualifier d'onomatopée. Il s'agit bien de reproduire à l'écrit un son émis par une personne qui manifeste ainsi sa perplexité, son indifférence ou son ignorance suivant le contexte.

Le mieux est d'indiquer dans la retranscription écrite le ton ou les mimiques employés par la personne ayant prononcé ce *prrt*.

Exemples tirés du *Corpus du français parlé au Québec*, [corpus 30](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/transcriptions/30_sous_corpus_30_f%C3%A9vrier2016.pdf), p 139 et [corpus 31](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/transcriptions/31_sous_corpus_31_d_cembre_2019_transcription.pdf) p 86 :

> M : m:ais là j’ai une décision à prendre euh je réflé [1chis je prends-tu un break d’un an deux ans trois ans/ ou je vas-tu m- me jeter là-dedans pour voir si j’aime ça la gé- gé- gérer plus/ (.) ou si j’aime vraiment pas ça pis je fais d’autre chose t’sais/ (il hausse une épaule comme pour minimiser l’importance de ce dont il est question) fait que c’est c’est: c’est vraiment pas un  [2un: **prrt** **(dit en haussant les épaules comme pour minimiser l’importance de ce dont il est question)** t’sais c’est euh: (.) disons {que euh:;que::} (.) Véronique est peut-être m- p- plus mal placée que moi dans sa job présentement (dit en riant) (RIRE) c’est pas  [3fin  [4hein/ <P139,L7>

> L : ben ça PERCE [1moins\ <p<aujourd’hui>> mais c’est comme sur la: la grève de deux mille douze  (en haussant les sourcils comme pour insister sur ses propos) peut-être plus proche de nous/ mais t’sais\ il y a eu\ une panoPLIE (en regardant vers le haut comme en signe d’exaspération) dans l’année: [2de vidéos qui ont suivi:\ [3là tout le monde en parlai:t\ [4(inaud.)     [5pis là ben\ [**prrt**] **(dit en haussant les sourcils et en arrondissant les lèvres comme pour minimiser l’importance de ce dont il est question)** on n’en parle plus du [6tout (0:09:12.5)

Answer (score 0):

C'est peut-être un bon sujet pour exercer son talent littéraire? Une petite périphrase évocatrice? "*Les lèvres du professeur émirent ce tremblement incertain qui reflétait toujours son doute...*". Evidemment, ce petit essai n'est pas talentueux du tout, mais il n'y a peut-être pas de mot unique qui va convenir parfaitement, le concept est trop riche.